# ASP.NET MVC 3 with service client as database access layer

Tags: c#, wcf, asp.net-mvc-3, session, roleprovider

I am writing an MVC 3 application, which doens't use the classic approach of accesing the database using the Entity Framework. Instead I have another application combined of WCF Services, which are used to manage the database access. Now I want to used those services in my MVC application, as the database access. This part is simple. The point where it gets harder is managing authentication and authorization in this scenario.

For authentication and authorization, I have created custom membership and role providers. I have implemented the necessary methods, but here I have ran into the problem. My services require username and password, to get the list of user roles.

I am wondering how can I store the username and password provided by user on logon, somewhere in the backed of my application, to make sure it is save, and to have the possability to use it in my role provider?

Is session the right choice for this? If so, how can I access user's session in my role provider?

Answer (score 1):

You should never use passwords, use password hashes instead (properly salted, of course). So, now you can pass username and password hash to your role provider which in turn will pass that to your wcf which will grant or not grant the necessary roles.

**Update**

IsUserInRole method should look like so:

```
public class WcfRoleProvider: RoleProvider
{
    public bool IsUserInRole(string username, roleName)
    {
        bool result = false;
        using(WcfRoleService roleService = new WcfRoleService())
        {
            result = roleService.IsUserInRole(username, roleName);
        }

        return result;
     }
}
```

Comment: I use password hashes  on the last level in the wcf service. But that doesnt solve my problem of storing the creditentials in the MVC app.

Comment: @Tromax why would you want to store them? They are passed each time that user makes a request by means of the auth cookie.

Comment: Anyway, in your IsUserInRole method, you only have userName and roleName as parameters, that means you don't need to have a user's password hash here by design. Because you already know that you have authenticated that user and your primary concern now is which roles that user has.

Comment: how can they be passed into my service client? I don't think this is true, but if you say that those values are stored in auth cookie, than maby I can somehow pass them from auth cookie to my service client?

Comment: @Tromax the thing is, you don't need to!

Comment: Okey... Than how is this passed? I probably lack some theory behind it and just use it bindlessly, so if you could point me to some article about it, or explain to me what I am doing wrong, and how should I use it I would be grateful.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8480/discussion-between-tromax-and-denis-valeev)